# Laravel problem loading 3 variables with query in a view

Tags: laravel

I am trying to load 3 queries  in a view, when loading 2 of the queries I have no problems, but when loading a third variable it returns the error:

```
 Facade\Ignition\Exceptions\ViewException
    Undefined variable: rejected

    Possible typo $rejected
    Did you mean $acept?
```

This is the code that I have in the method, check the 3 queries with var_dump and the 3 show the data that should

```
public function Myproposal(){
            $id=auth()->user()->usu_id;
    
              $acept['acept']= DB::table('detail_proposal')
            ->join('proposal','proposal.pro_id','=','detail_proposal.pro_id')
            ->join('home','home.home_id','=','detail_proposal.home_id')
            ->select('home.home_nom','home.home_img','proposal.pro_id','proposal.int_date')
            ->where('users.usu_id','=',$id)
            ->where('proposal.estate_id','=',1)
            ->get();
    
    
    
              $active['active']= DB::table('detail_proposal')
            ->join('proposal','proposal.pro_id','=','detail_proposal.pro_id')
            ->join('home','home.home_id','=','detail_proposal.home_id')
            ->select('home.home_nom','home.home_img','proposal.pro_id','proposal.int_date')
            ->where('users.usu_id','=',$id)
            ->where('proposal.estate_id','=',3)
            ->get();
    
             $rejected['rejected']= DB::table('detail_proposal')
            ->join('proposal','proposal.pro_id','=','detail_proposal.pro_id')
            ->join('home','home.home_id','=','detail_proposal.home_id')
            ->select('home.home_nom','home.home_img','proposal.pro_id','proposal.pro_date')
            ->where('users.usu_id','=',$id)
            ->where('proposal.estate_id','=',2)
            ->get();
    
        return view('proposal.Myproposal',$acept,$active,$rejected);
        }

  @foreach($acept as $acepts)
<tr>
            <td>{{$loop->iteration}}</td>
            <td>{{$acepts->home_nom}} </td>
            <td>{{$acepts->pro_date}} </td>
            
</tr>
@endforeach



  @foreach($active as $actives)
<tr>
            <td>{{$loop->iteration}}</td>
            <td>{{$actives->home_nom}} </td>
            <td>{{$actives->pro_date}} </td>
            
</tr>
@endforeach



  @foreach($rejected as $rejecteds)
<tr>
            <td>{{$loop->iteration}}</td>
            <td>{{$rejecteds->home_nom}} </td>
            <td>{{$rejecteds->pro_date}} </td>
            
</tr>
@endforeach
```

This is the code that I have in the view, the variables $accept and $active load the data, but putting the variable $rejected produces the error marking this line:

```
 @foreach($rejected as $rejecteds)
```

I don't understand why the error occurs with the third variable, since it contains data, how can I solve it?

Comment: Variables should be passed to the view as an array. Try like this `return view('proposal.Myproposal', ['acept' => $acept, 'active' => $active, 'rejected' => $rejected]);`.

Comment: I receive this error: Property [home_nom] does not exist on this collection instance. with var_dump I know that the variables have data

Comment: problem solved modify queries by removing the ['acept']['active']['rejected']

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not passing any data to the view that has a `rejected` key. The `view` helper function only takes 3 arguments, you are calling it with 4.

```
function view($view = null, $data = [], $mergeData = [])
```

You can just make one array and pass that:

```
$data['acept'] = ...;
$data['active'] = ...;
$data['rejected'] = ...;

return view(..., $data);
```